# model.fit_generator python error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, generator

I get this error when I run my code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1/thesis2/CNN_dwt2.py", line 437, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user1/thesis2/CNN_dwt2.py", line 316, in main
    history=model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, end=75), 
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1815, in fit_generator
    return self.fit(
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1049, in fit
    data_handler = data_adapter.DataHandler(
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 1122, in __init__
    dataset = dataset.map(_make_class_weight_map_fn(class_weight))
  File "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 1295, in _make_class_weight_map_fn
    class_ids = list(sorted(class_weight.keys()))

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

I don't understand what does this error mean and How to solve it ??

Any help would be appreciated.

**code**:

```
def generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, paths, start=0, end=100):       
    while True:
        from_=int(len(paths)/100*start)
        to_=int(len(paths)/100*end)
        for i in range(from_, int(to_)):
            f=paths[i]
            x = np.load(PathSpectogramFolder+f)
     if('P' in f):
                y = np.repeat([[0,1]],x.shape[0], axis=0)
            else:
                y =np.repeat([[1,0]],x.shape[0], axis=0) 
            yield(x,y)
history=model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, filesPath, end=75)
```

Comment: Hi, @Edayildiz can you tell me what is the type of  class_weight?

Comment: @Tfer3 I don't know what is `class_weight`. `generate_arrays_for_training` return `x` and `y` . `x` is a 2D array of float numbers and `y` is [0,1].

Comment: @Tfer3 I am waiting for your reply.

Comment: Please provide more information. Data shapes and sizes, the code for `model`, etc.